# Google structured data for watercrafts - which category?

Tags: seo, structured-data

I have a page www.mynautics.com and I am testing structured data now.

All data is correctly downloaded by Google and shown in structured data testing tool, but is not showing in Google results. I believe that is due to a lack of category data.

But looking trough Google's taxonomy (https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160081) I can not find proper category - watercrafts or boats...

Should I just put ads on my website in category Vehicles & Parts? Is there any better solution?

Any ideas?

Comment: How long have you waited to see rich snippet data in Google's index  for your site results? Have Google revisited your website and crawled the new markup?

Comment: Yes .. Google revisited and from webmasters tools console I can see data (no images is shown - I don't know why) and status is 0 errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you are referring to on Google is a Google merchant page, meaning it is meant for displaying products as paid results, it has nothing to do with schema.org and structured data.

Google does not display all schemas as rich snippets but tagging your data with appropriate schemas will help Google understand your content better and maybe give you a little ranking boost. You can refer to the page below for a list of supported rich snippets, but this does guarantee you will get them, even if your pages are tagged. Most sites that get rich snippets need to be authoritative in their field, have a verified Google+ account (using rel author / publisher is also recommended) connected to the main site and have fresh content updated on a regular basis.

As for the ads, Adsense automatically decides which ads to show, choosing you site category in Adsense will not affect that.

Hope i managed to answer your questions..

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en